# Bad file descriptor issue in C shell

Tags: c, file, shell, file-descriptor

I am writing my own shell for a homework assignment, and am running into this issue:

Whenever I enter a command to redirect output to a file (i.e. ls -al > output.txt) my shell should handle the command and redirect the output. However, I keep getting this message displayed: `ls: write error: Bad file descriptor`

I saw on a few other forums that it might be in reference to exceeding the amount of memory, but I don't see how that could be the issue. Here's a bit of my code (if you need more for clarity, feel free to ask):

```
loc[0] = argv[0];                 //used for execution

while(argv[count] != 0){                    //loop through commands
    if(strcmp(argv[count], "<") == 0)    //and test for certain flags
        inFlag = 1;
    else if(strcmp(argv[count], ">") == 0){
        argv[count] = argv[count+1] = 0;
        outFlag = 1;
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[count], "&") == 0)
        bgFlag == 1;
    else if(strcmp(argv[count], "|") == 0){
        argv[count] = 0;
        loc[pipes+1] = argv[count+1];
        pipes++;
    }
        count++;
}

for(k = 0; k <= pipes; k++){
    if(j < pipes){
        pipe(r_tube);
        j++;
    }

    pid = fork();

    if(pid > 0){
        if(j > 0){
            close(l_tube[0]);
            close(l_tube[1]);
        }
        l_tube[0] = r_tube[0];
        l_tube[1] = r_tube[1];
    }
    else if(pid == 0){
        if((k == 0) && (inFlag == 1)){
            int n = open("input.txt", "r");
            close (0);
            dup (n);
            close (n);
        }
        else if((k > 0) && (k < pipes)){

        }
        else if((k == pipes) && (outFlag == 1)){   //<-----issue
            int out = open("output.txt", 0666);
            close (1);
            dup (out);
            close (out);
        }
        else if(k == pipes){

        }
        execvp(argv[loc[k]], &argv[loc[k]]);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
count = 0;

loc[0] = argv[0];                 //used for execution

count++;
pipes++;

char* outFile = NULL;
char* inFile = NULL;

while(argv[count] != 0)
{ 
    if(strcmp(argv[count], "<") == 0)
    { 
        inFile = strdup(argv[count+1]);
        inFlag = 1;
        count++;
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[count], ">") == 0)
    {
        outFile = strdup(argv[count+1]);
        outFlag = 1;
        count++;
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[count], "&") == 0)
    {
        bgFlag == 1;
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[count], "|") == 0)
    {
        argv[count] = 0;
        loc[pipes] = argv[count+1];
        pipes++;
    }

    count++;
}

int current_out = STDOUT_FILENO;
int current_in = STDIN_FILENO;
int next_in = STDIN_FILENO;

for(k = 0; k <= pipes; k++)
{
    int cur_pipes[2];

    int last_out = current_out;
    int last_in = current_in;

    if(k < pipes)
    {
        pipe(cur_pipes);
        current_out = cur_pipes[1];
        current_in = next_in;
        next_in = cur_pipes[0];
    }

    else if (k == pipes)
    {
        current_out = STDOUT_FILENO;
        current_in = next_in;
    }

    pid = fork();

    if(pid > 0)
    {
        if(k > 0)
        {
            close(last_out);
            close(last_in);
        }
    }
    else if(pid == 0)
    {
        if((k == 0) && (inFlag == 1))
        {
            int n = open(inFile, O_RDONLY);
            if (n == -1) 
            {
                printf("Could not open input file!\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            current_in = n;
        }

        if((k == pipes) && (outFlag == 1))
        {
            int n = open(outFile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
            if (n == -1) {
                printf("Could not open output file!\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            current_out = n;
        }       

        if (current_in != STDIN_FILENO)
        {
            close (STDIN_FILENO);
            dup (current_in);
            close (current_in);
        }

        if(current_out != STDOUT_FILENO)
        {
            close(STDOUT_FILENO);
            dup(current_out);
            close(current_out);
        }

        execvp(argv[loc[k]], &argv[loc[k]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, it turns out that I actually can't open the file (it returns the printf statement). Is there a way to fix this? Could it be in my permissions (0666)?

Comment: In my directory, the file "output.txt" is already present (in the same directory as this shell program). How would I set the pwd write permissions?

Comment: The changes solved that issue, but are now causing another. If you notice in my code, after seeing that ">" is present, I set both the ">" and the output file name to NULL. I was receiving this error, which I am now receiving again: ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory

Comment: The compiler is not accepting "O_RDONLY", "O_WRONLY", "O_CREAT". It's treating them as variables, and calling them undefined. So I have no way to check this. Is there a specific library I need to #include in order for these to become keywords?

Comment: I was missing one #include :P        But after getting the commands to work, it is still bring up that same error: "ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory"

Comment: No, the file I am redirecting to comes after the > symbol. The problem boils down to this now: how do I get the command to redirect to the output file, without trying to write to > ? I can't delete the > because that's the only way I can set the flag. And the execvp is taking whatever command is in argv[x] and executing it.

Comment: That is what I'm doing. However, my execvp is executing a position in the array "loc", which is storing the starting points of each line of code (terminated by a NULL or 0 in argv). So, when execvp goes to execute loc[k], it will execute, for example, "ls -al > output.txt". That's where the error is coming from.

Comment: Well, thank you for all of the help regardless! I will take a look at this and make it work.

Comment: You've posted a large amount of code, without explaining what you've changed and why you've done it. That's not very useful for other people visiting the site to track down similar issues. Providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

int open(const char *pathname, int flags, ... /* mode_t mode */);

You need an access mode in order to determine what you are going to do with the file. For example (O_WRONLY - write only or O_RDONLY - read only)...btw there are alot more than these 2.

Comment: I pointed this out to him already. He was using the standard C open flags, rather than the POSIX open flags. There were issues beyond just this though.